# How to import CSV file to Rhino using Python and connect the points using interpCRV command

Tags: python, csv, rhino, rhinoceros

I have a program that interpolates between different predefined geometries and outputs a CSV file with points defined by X Y Z columns.  For instance:

1,5,0.2

3,4,0.2

1,5,0.3

3,4,0.3

I am trying to import that file into Rhino, and have any points with a common Z value connect by a _interpCRV *In the order they are imported*  The end result is that I'll have similar shapes (like a circle) at different Z values.  I will have to manipulate the geometry further after that, but I am having difficulty getting this first step started.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would be nice if you can show us what you've tried and we'll help you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

you can import point from txt with this:

```
def ReadPointsDef(filename):

if not filename: return

#read each line from the file
file = open(filename, "r")
#list of lines
contents = file.readlines()
#contents = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
file.close()

# points=[]
points3d = Rhino.Collections.Point3dList()
for text in contents:
    items = text.strip("()\n").split(",")    
    if len(items)==3:
        x = float(items[0])
        y = float(items[1])
        z = float(items[2])
        points3d.Add(x,y,z)

#contents = [__point_from_string(line) for line in contents]
#return points
return points3d
```

Then use wherever you want, like this sample:

```
points = ReadPointsDef("C:/Users/UsuarioStd/Documents/points.txt")
interCurve = rs.AddInterpCurve(points,3,4) 
rs.ObjectColor(interCurve, [255,0,0])#rojo
```

You must to group by Z and use the groups to build your curves.
Yor must to give more information about the output taht you want, a graph would be good.
Greetings